# Not receiving texts from one person

Tags: mms

I have an Razer Phone 2 android phone with Android 9 (Build Number P-SMR3-RC002-RZR-200226.3141).  I've been on Android for about 2 years, before that Windows phone, then Android before that.  I've never had an iPhone.  I did change from a TMobile MVNO to a Verizon MVNO about four months ago.  My wife is a long time iPhone user and has been using Verizon for a couple of years.  My dad is a long time Android user, not sure what carrier.

I recently realized that I'm not seeing texts from my dad in an MMS thread to my wife and I.  She sees texts from both of us.  I only see her texts.  I'm using the default Messages App.

I see MMS texts from my Android and iPhone using friends.  I've definitely seen MMS texts from my dad up until a few weeks ago.

The only way I'm aware that this can happen is if I recently switched from IPhone to Android and he had formerly sent me texts from an IPhone, but neither my dad nor I have ever had an iPhone.  I checked in the phone app and his phone number isn't blocked.

Thinking about trying a reset.

Comment: Before a reset, please check if your messaging app is updated. Or try with a different messaging app. If this still happens, try it in *safe mode* (Google instructions for your device). [Edit] to add device and Android version details and the messaging app you are  using.

Comment: I tried the Textra app, but it doesn't show my dad's texts either.

Comment: I restarted in safe mode and his texts don't show up.  If I do a reset will it redownload my texts from my carrier?

Comment: No they won't be downloaded again. On factory reset All user data and apps are deleted. Read more about [factory reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)// with Textra or on in safe mode, did you ask your father to send SMS and check? That's the way to confirm. Just by downloading Textra or entering safe mode, those missing messages don't show up automatically